# android architecture components + retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I've followed the [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) from Google to get started with Android Architecture Components and Retrofit. Everything works fine but I have troubles in my own data model because of foreign keys.

Let's say I have a place :

```
@Entity(tableName = "place",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = User::class, parentColumns = ["user_id"], childColumns = ["place_created_by_user_id"])
    ],
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["place_created_by_user_id"], name = "place_created_by_user_index")
    ]) 
data class Place(

    @SerializedName("id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "place_id")
    var id: Long,

    @SerializedName("name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "place_name")
    var name: String?,

    @SerializedName("created_by_user_id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "place_created_by_user_id")
    var createdByUserId: Long?,
)
```

And a user :

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(

    @SerializedName("id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
    var id: Long,

    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_first_name")
    var firstName: String,

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_last_name")
    var lastName: String,
)
```

Following the sample of Google, the method to fetch the places in the repository is :

```
fun loadPlaces(): LiveData<Resource<List<Place>>> {

    return object : NetworkBoundResource<List<Place>, List<Place>>(appExecutors) {

        override fun saveCallResult(item: List<Place>) {
            placeDao.insert(item)
        }

        override fun shouldFetch(data: List<Place>?): Boolean = true

        override fun loadFromDb() = placeDao.getAll()

        override fun createCall() = service.getPlaces()

        override fun onFetchFailed() {
            //repoListRateLimit.reset(owner)
        }
    }.asLiveData()
}
```

So normally, it would simply work (I tried with an entity without foreign key) but it failed because of the foreign constraint :

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)
```

Indeed, the user is not loaded yet. 
So before `placeDao.insert(item)`, I have to load each users to make sure the place will find his user. And it's the same for each entities and each foreign keys. 
Any ideas of how can I achieve this following this architecture?

The point is when I call `loadPlaces()` in my ViewModel like this :

```
class PlacesViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModel(application) {
    val places: LiveData<Resource<List<Place>>> = repository.loadPlaces()
}
```

The repository would intrinsically load the users attached to the places...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you manage to make this work @Benjamin?